# How to read a block of pattern file?

Tags: python, design-patterns, block

I have some pattern files that I like to read just a few parts of them.

Exemple: text.txt

```
Recipe: 
'name' 
Ingredients:
Item 1
Item 2
Item N... 
How to prepare:
Item 1
Item 2
Item N...
```

I'd like to get only the ingredients.

Comment: Understood. I'm sorry... Actually I'm using python Kivymd, and I'm trying to understand how it's work in Python code, that's why I didn't put some code.

Comment: Well, needing to do something in Python is a great opportunity to learn the language instead of trying to get other to write the code for you. Because I now understand what you're doing I *am* going to downvote your question. Note I also rolled-back your update where you put the accepted answer in your question — there's seldom a need to do that here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
handle = open("test.txt", "r")
lines = handle.readlines()
lines = [line.strip() for line in lines]
st_idx = lines.index("Ingredients:")
ed_idx = lines.index("How to prepare:")
Ingredients = lines[st_idx:ed_idx]
```

Comment: While this code *may* answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: It worked... As Martineau said, a little explanation would be helpful, but I'm a little familiarize with Python, so I could understand the code.